# C# send values of dynamically created textboxes to another users of this program

Tags: c#, winforms, data-synchronization

I am working on project in which I need to send values of dynamiclly created textboxes.
I need values to be changed in another computer when I change It in mine.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

static int itimes = 0;
static int i = 0;
public void textboxadd()
{            
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Name = "Name" + i;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        Point p = new Point(6, 43);
        txt.Location = p;
    }
    else
    {
        Point p = new Point(6, 43 + 32 * i); 
        txt.Location = p;
    }

    txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 26);

    Properties.Settings.Default.name1 = txt.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();


    groupBox1.Controls.Add(txt);

    i++;           
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    textboxadd();
    int gps = groupBox1.Size.Height;
    if (itimes == 0)
    {
        itimes++;
    }
    else
    {
        groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(248, gps + 32);
    }
}
}
```

If you don't understand my question please ask and I will answer.

Comment: well i did not get this " I need values to be changed in another computer when I change It in mine" could you please give some example?

Comment: as i understand this OP is trying to sync individual instances of the application across multiple nodes of a network ... the interesting questions would be: number of instances? the internet or a local network? ... there is a probability that a simple WCF service can handle this in near real time ...

Comment: When I will change textboxes values in my computer, I want this values to appear  in another computer (which is using this application) instantly. Is it possible???

Comment: ok... easy words ... yes ... but there are still a few open questions: how many computers are we talking about? ... how are these computers connected? are they on the same company LAN, or is one located on Site A and the next one is located on Site B a few thousand miles away, with just the internet as a connection? .... regarding "instantly" ... the more computers involved in this, the more deley you will get ... the further away they are from each other, the more deley you will get. That ranges from a few miliseconds to seconds or minutes if we are talking about a few hundred thousands PCs

Comment: Can i just connect them into sql server? max distance of computers is 10 miles.

Comment: @user2971569 Yes you can, but you would have to have your db accessible online - web server probably.

Comment: how make my db accessible

Comment: As I said, it would have be on a web server that is visible from the internet. There are many hosting providers with db included. Just choose. By the way, it does not seem that any other answer should have appear - are you not satisfied with my answer? You are asking for so many information at once.